# Trigonometric Simplification Question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I was working through a trigonometry problem, and was having some difficulty so I decided to look at the solution. Here are the steps:

$$\frac{\sin(2x+50^\circ)+\sin(150^\circ)}{\sin(2x+50^\circ)-\sin(150^\circ)}=\frac{\cos(50^\circ)-\cos(2x+50^\circ)}{\cos(50^\circ)+\cos(2x+50^\circ)}$$
$$\frac{\sin(2x+50^\circ)}{\sin150^\circ}=\frac{-\cos50^\circ}{\cos(2x+50^\circ)}$$

[(Image that replaced text.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rF1wv.png)

I am not exactly how the solution got from the first step to the second one. I would just like some clarification on the intermediate step.

Comment: https://qcweb.qc.edu.hk/math/Junior%20Secondary/Componendo%20et%20Dividendo.htm

Comment: This method is called "**componendo-dividendo** in maths. If `a / b` = `c / d`
Then `[(a+b)/(a-b)]` =`[(c+d)/(c-d)]`

Answer (score 7):

$$\frac{a+b}{a-b}=\frac{c-d}{c+d}$$

$$ac+ad+bc+bd=ac-ad-bc+bd$$

$$2ad=-2bc$$

$$\frac{a}{b}=-\frac{c}{d}$$

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to Siong's answer, but written differently using ratios:
\begin{align}
\frac{a+b}{a-b} - 1 &= \frac{c-d}{c+d} -1 \\[2ex]
\require{cancel} \frac{2b}{a-b} &= -\frac{2d}{c+d} \\[2ex]
\frac{a-b}{b} &= -\frac{c+d}{d} \\[2ex]
\frac{a}{b} - 1 &= -\frac{c}{d} -1 \\
\end{align}